# How to parse links in HTML page?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I want to parse list of links from this [website](https://www.over-view.com/digital-index/)

I am trying to do this with request library in Python. However, when I try to read the HTML with bs4 there aren't any links. Just empty `ul`:

```
< ul class="ais-Hits-list">< /ul >
```

How can I get these links?

Edit:
The code I tried so far:

```
link = "https://www.over-view.com/digital-index/"
r = requests.get(link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

Comment: Can u include the code you have tried so far.

Comment: I guess the links are added by JavaScript. In that case you can not parse them with beautifulsoup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since information load dynamically on that website, you can use `selenium` to collect required information:

```py
import time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")

path_to_chromedriver ='chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=path_to_chromedriver)

driver.get('https://www.over-view.com/digital-index/')

time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
rows = soup.select("ul.ais-Hits-list > li > a")

for row in rows:
    print(row.get('href'))
```

Example of output:

```
/overviews/adelaide-canola-flowers
/overviews/adelaide-rift-complex
/overviews/adriatic-tankers
/overviews/adventuredome
/overviews/agricultural-development
/overviews/agricultural-development
/overviews/agricultural-development
/overviews/agriculture-development
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a bit more extravagant way: don't judge to harsh since I've tried this approach for the first time, but you can make the same request to the API as their frontend does. Plus, this code executes asynchronously thanks to **asyncio** + **aiohttp**.

Keep in mind, that I took arbitrary number of pages to iterate over and didn't handle possible errors (you need to fine tune it).

#### Code without Selenium WebDriver

```
import json
import asyncio

import aiohttp

URL = "https://ai7o5ij8d5-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/*/queries?x-algolia-agent=Algolia for JavaScript (3.35.1); Browser (lite); react (16.13.1); react-instantsearch (5.7.0); JS Helper (2.28.0)&x-algolia-application-id=AI7O5IJ8D5&x-algolia-api-key=7f1a509e834f885835edcfd3482b990c"


async def scan_single_digital_index_page(page_num, session):
    body = {
        "requests": [
            {
                "indexName": "overview",
                "params": f"query=&hitsPerPage=30&maxValuesPerFacet=10&page={page_num}&highlightPreTag=%3Cais-highlight-0000000000%3E&highlightPostTag=%3C%2Fais-highlight-0000000000%3E&facets=%5B%22_tags.name%22%5D&tagFilters=",
            }
        ]
    }
    async with session.post(URL, json=body) as resp:
        received_data = await resp.json()
        results = received_data.get("results")
        hits = results[0].get("hits")
        links = list()
        for hit in hits:
            for key, value in hit.items():
                if key == "slug":
                    links.append("https://www.over-view.com/overviews/" + value)
        return links


async def scan_all_digital_index_pages(session):
    tasks = list()
    max_pages = 20
    for page_num in range(1, max_pages):
        task = asyncio.create_task(scan_single_digital_index_page(page_num, session))
        tasks.append(task)
    all_lists = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    # Unpack all lists with links into a single set of all links.
    all_links = set()
    for l in all_lists:
        all_links.update(l)
    return all_links


async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        all_links = await scan_all_digital_index_pages(session)
        for link in all_links:
            print(link)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

#### Example result for the first page

```
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/adelaide-canola-flowers
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/adelaide-rift-complex
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/adriatic-tankers
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/adventuredome
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/agricultural-development
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/agricultural-development
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/agricultural-development
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/agriculture-development
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/akimiski-island
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/al-falah-housing-project
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/alabama-tornadoes
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/alakol-lake
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/albenga
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/albuquerque-baseball-complex
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/alta-wind-energy-center
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/altocumulus-clouds
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/amsterdam
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/anak-krakatoa-eruption-juxtapose
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/ancient-ruins-of-palmyra
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/andean-mountain-vineyards
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/angas-inlet-trees
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/angkor-wat
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/ankara-residential-development
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/antofagasta-chile
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/apple-park
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/aquatica-water-park
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/aral-sea
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/arc-de-triomphe
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/arecibo-observatory
https://www.over-view.com/overviews/arizona-rock-formations
```

For future changes (as there are many moving parts) you can get the info about their API from Web Console in browser

[image: Web Console in Firefox browser]